# Galerkin FEM error when using even number of elements

Tags: linear-algebra, matlab, finite-element

## Intro:

I am developing a Galerkin FEM code in matlab - starting small with a simple 1D ODE. The equation I'm trying to solve is: $$a u_x = cos(x), x \in [0, 2\pi]$$ Which has a known exact solution $$ u = sin(x)/a $$

When I solve the equation using my code on an odd number of linear elements (nodes = N+1), the solution is as expected:

[image: Sample FEM Solution - Odd number Elements]

---

## Problem

I'm running into a problem when I set the number of elements to an even number, in which case the solution vector is just filled with NaNs and I receive the following warning/error:

> Warning: Matrix is singular to working precision

Most of the questions I've looked up on mathworks answers have to do with incorrectly constructed matrices - that's not the case here. I'm not sure if I'm running into a numerical issue, where a zero is too small, or if this is an implementation issue.

I construct both the elemental stiffness matrices and the RHS vector in the same way, and I can't tell a difference between the two systems from a quick comparison of their respective **Ax**=**b** structures.

---

## Methodology

I'm generating the elemental stiffness matrices individually, where *N* is a basis function. The weak form of the ODE above for an elemental stiffness matrix is:
$$ I_e = \int_\Omega \underline{N} a u_x dx = \int_\Omega \underline{N} cos(x) dx $$

Using integration by parts (i.e. *magic*), this equation turns into this:
$$ (au) \underline{N} |_{\partial \Omega L}^{\partial \Omega R} - \int_\Omega (au) \underline{N}_x dx $$

Then I substitute a continuous value of u for the weighted sum of node values ($\hat{u}$), as such:
$$ u = N_1 \hat{u}_1 + N_2 \hat{u}_2 = \underline{N}^\intercal \underline{\hat{u}} $$

Which is finally equal to the following:

$$ I_e = a \underline{N}^\intercal \underline{\hat{u}} \underline{N} |_{\partial \Omega L}^{\partial \Omega R} - a \int_\Omega \underline{N}^\intercal \underline{\hat{u}} \underline{N}_x dx  $$

Since the first term in $I_e$ cancels out except for the boundaries, in which case $u$ is already 0, I'm assuming that term can be safely ignored. The resulting elemental stiffness takes the form:

$$ I_e = \begin{bmatrix} -a \int_\Omega N_1 N_{1x} dx & -a \int_\Omega N_1 N_{2x} dx \\ -a \int_\Omega N_2 N_{1x} dx & -a \int_\Omega N_2 N_{2x} dx \end{bmatrix} $$

---

## Code

The entire code is in a repository on my github [here](https://github.com/cbcoutinho/simple1D_CG-FE), but the most important part is here below. All of the functions called from this script have been checked and verified to work properly, namely basis_1D(), lgquad(), and lgwt(). Feel free to check the repo if you're curious

The portion of the code that constructs **A** and **b** is:

```
for kk = 1:numElem
    % Initialize elemental stiffness matrix
    Ie  = zeros(2);

    % Anonymous function that maps natural coordinate to global coordinate
    X   = @(s)basis_1D(1,1,s,0)*coordPairs(kk,1) + ...
                basis_1D(1,2,s,0)*coordPairs(kk,2); % X = x(s)

    % Anonymous function that calculates the Jacobian as a function of the natural coordinate
    J   = @(s)basis_1D(1,1,s,1)*coordPairs(kk,1) + ...
                basis_1D(1,2,s,1)*coordPairs(kk,2); % J = dx/ds 

    for ii = 1:2
        for jj = 1:2
            % Anonymous function to what I denote above as N_x
            fun1    = @(s) basis_1D(1,ii,s,1)./J(s);

            % Anonymous function to what I denote above as N
            fun2    = @(s) basis_1D(1,jj,s,0);

            % The two functions combined together, as well as the jacobian for numerical quadrature
            fun     = @(s) fun1(s)*fun2(s).*J(s);

            Ie(ii,jj) = -a*lgquad(fun,[],-1,1); % Calling Guass-Legendre Quad routine

            II = (kk-1)+ii;
            JJ = (kk-1)+jj;
            A(II,JJ) = A(II,JJ) + Ie(ii,jj); % Assembling global matrix
        end

        fun1    = @(s) cos(X(s));
        fun2    = @(s) basis_1D(1,ii,s,0);
        fun     = @(s) fun1(s)*fun2(s).*J(s); % Combined function for RHS

        % Calling Gauss-Legendre Quad routine and assembling RHS
        b((kk-1)+ii) = b((kk-1)+ii) + lgquad(fun,[],-1,1);
    end
end
```

Can someone give me an idea of what my issue might be?

Comment: I believe your fundamental problem is that you are trying to prescribe two boundary conditions for a first-order ODE. I modified your code to prescribe a BC only at the left end and it seems to give correct results for both even and odd numbers of elements. However, I don't understand why your code apparently works as-is for an odd number of elements.

Comment: @BillGreene, you were right, removing the second Dirichlet BC solved the problem. I'm guessing that I created an overdetermined system by including BCs - I'll remember that for next time.

I'm not sure why an odd number of elements works either, but I appreciate that you reminded me of that issue. Thanks again!